# Help moving forward after modIndices() in lavaan

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I’m running a model in SEM using lavaan. I’ve really run into a puzzle I can’t quite seem to solve and I would love to tap into everyone’s expertise to help provide some direction. Below I’ve added the steps I’ve taken so far to help shed light on my attempt at Sherlock Holms-ing this situation. Apologies in advance for the length of the post, but hopefully there’s some other brains out there that thrive on solving problems like these.

Please see the image below for my original model. The model is pretty basic with latent variable RL (responsive leadership) predicting latent variable PI (personal initiative) while controlling for manifest gender, manifest ethnicity, latent Control, and latent Cplex (complexity).

[image]

Additionally, here is the code I used for the original model:

```
SEMmodel2 <- '# Latent variables
RL =~ 1*RL_1 + RL_2 + RL_3 + RL_4 + RL_5 + RL_6 + RL_7 + RL_8 + RL_9 + RL_10 + RL_11 + RL_12
PI =~ 1*PI_1 + PI_2 + PI_3 + PI_4 + PI_5 + PI_6 + PI_7 
Cplex =~ 1*Cplex_1 + Cplex_2 + Cplex_3 + Cplex_4
Control =~ 1*Cont_1 + Cont_2 + Cont_3 + Cont_4

#regressions
PI ~ RL + Age + Cplex + Control + Gen2 + Eth1 + Eth2 + Eth4 + Eth5' 

SEMmodel2 <- lavaan(SEMmodel2, data = dat2, auto.var = TRUE, fixed.x = FALSE, int.ov.free = TRUE, estimator = "dwls")
summary(SEMmodel2, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
```

When I ran this model, the model fit wasn’t the best (it wasn’t horrible, but it didn’t meet any cutoffs). For character limit sake, here are a quick summary of some important pieces of the output instead of the full output: CFI = .747, RMSEA = .157, SRMR = .169. Factor loadings between .56 and .86. PI to RL path had a beta of .54 and p <.001.

So, I decided to check the modification indices to see if there were any suggestions that theoretically made sense to modify. I ran the following code:

```
MOD <- modificationIndices(SEMmodel2, free.remove = TRUE, na.remove = TRUE, sort. = TRUE)
subset(MOD, mi >1000)
```

**And this is where I get tripped up.** The top modification indices that are suggested are some paths that are already in my model but just reversed. For instance, PI ~ RL is the main IV to DV path that is in the model. The modification indices are telling me to add RL ~ PI on top of that path, though. It does this with a couple of the covariates as well (control, cplex). See output below:

```
subset(MOD, mi >1000)
  lhs op     rhs       mi   epc sepc.lv sepc.all sepc.nox
     RL  ~      PI 4918.437 1.468   1.007    1.007    1.007
Control  ~      PI 4118.074 1.563   1.177    1.177    1.177     
Control  ~      RL 3241.769 0.573   0.629    0.629    0.629
     RL  ~ Control 3241.769 0.690   0.629    0.629    0.629
     RL ~~ Control 3241.769 0.775   0.629    0.629    0.629
  Cplex  ~      PI 2525.688 1.197   0.973    0.973    0.973
     RL ~~   Cplex 1667.477 0.561   0.491    0.491    0.491
  Cplex  ~      RL 1667.477 0.414   0.491    0.491    0.491
     RL  ~   Cplex 1667.477 0.583   0.491    0.491    0.491
```

From these suggestions I tried two different model fixes – both have issues and I’m not sure how to move forward. Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

---

***Fix 1:* Add in path RL ~ PI**

My inclination is that adding this arrow into the model – like the following image – would make it non-recursive and basically means that RL predicts PI and PI in turn predicts RL. If I add in that path to the model, the model fit is great but there are multiple betas that are above 1 which is concerning (see output below). *I’m not as clear with the underlying mathematics that go into this type of analysis. Can someone explain the implications of this and what it would mean about steps forward?*

[image]

Here is the output for adding in the non-recursive path:

```
summary(SEMmodel2_3, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
lavaan 0.6-3 ended normally after 150 iterations

  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         85

  Number of observations                           506

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Model Fit Test Statistic                    1330.226
  Degrees of freedom                               476
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic            24118.401
  Degrees of freedom                               513
  P-value                                        0.000

User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.964
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.961

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.060
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.056  0.063
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.076

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured
  Standard Errors                             Standard

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  RL =~                                                                 
    RL_1              1.000                               1.176    0.817
    RL_2              0.968    0.029   32.879    0.000    1.139    0.858
    RL_3              0.894    0.028   31.569    0.000    1.052    0.796
    RL_4              1.000    0.031   32.592    0.000    1.177    0.812
    RL_5              0.943    0.029   32.449    0.000    1.109    0.831
    RL_6              0.992    0.031   32.417    0.000    1.168    0.844
    RL_7              0.978    0.030   32.764    0.000    1.150    0.846
    RL_8              0.877    0.028   31.560    0.000    1.032    0.801
    RL_9              1.007    0.031   32.855    0.000    1.185    0.867
    RL_10             0.781    0.025   31.113    0.000    0.919    0.782
    RL_11             0.935    0.029   32.153    0.000    1.099    0.800
    RL_12             0.891    0.028   31.675    0.000    1.048    0.804
  PI =~                                                                 
    PI_1              1.000                               0.794    0.726
    PI_2              0.897    0.036   25.161    0.000    0.712    0.632
    PI_3              1.052    0.040   26.039    0.000    0.836    0.713
    PI_4              1.226    0.044   27.748    0.000    0.974    0.790
    PI_5              1.154    0.043   26.887    0.000    0.917    0.728
    PI_6              1.002    0.041   24.271    0.000    0.795    0.625
    PI_7              1.071    0.040   26.505    0.000    0.850    0.711
  Cplex =~                                                              
    Cplex_1           1.000                               0.807    0.484
    Cplex_2           0.866    0.060   14.429    0.000    0.699    0.407
    Cplex_3           1.654    0.090   18.335    0.000    1.335    0.864
    Cplex_4           1.464    0.080   18.266    0.000    1.182    0.892
  Control =~                                                            
    Cont_1            1.000                               1.044    0.775
    Cont_2            0.984    0.037   26.470    0.000    1.027    0.772
    Cont_3            0.948    0.038   25.247    0.000    0.990    0.727
    Cont_4            1.136    0.041   27.373    0.000    1.186    0.904

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv Std.all
  PI ~                                                                  
    RL               -0.782    0.081   -9.631    0.000   -1.159   -1.159
    Age               0.021    0.003    5.922    0.000    0.026    0.234
    Cplex             1.098    0.094   11.672    0.000    1.117    1.117
    Control           1.009    0.072   14.013    0.000    1.327    1.327
    Gen2             -0.113    0.059   -1.915    0.056   -0.142   -0.068
    Eth1              0.727    0.122    5.979    0.000    0.915    0.294
    Eth2              0.025    0.089    0.278    0.781    0.031    0.009
    Eth4              0.294    0.119    2.474    0.013    0.371    0.085
    Eth5              0.878    0.405    2.166    0.030    1.106    0.120
  RL ~                                                                  
    PI                1.548    0.063   24.687    0.000    1.045    1.045

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Age ~~                                                                
    Gen2              0.481    0.197    2.440    0.015    0.481    0.112
    Eth1             -0.490    0.098   -4.986    0.000   -0.490   -0.170
    Eth2             -0.065    0.120   -0.541    0.589   -0.065   -0.025
    Eth4             -0.219    0.076   -2.889    0.004   -0.219   -0.107
    Eth5              0.005    0.045    0.112    0.911    0.005    0.005
  Gen2 ~~                                                               
    Eth1              0.011    0.007    1.562    0.118    0.011    0.073
    Eth2             -0.004    0.006   -0.653    0.514   -0.004   -0.028
    Eth4             -0.010    0.004   -2.344    0.019   -0.010   -0.092
    Eth5             -0.002    0.002   -1.143    0.253   -0.002   -0.044
  Eth1 ~~                                                               
    Eth2             -0.011    0.002   -5.749    0.000   -0.011   -0.116
    Eth4             -0.006    0.001   -4.731    0.000   -0.006   -0.088
    Eth5             -0.001    0.001   -2.388    0.017   -0.001   -0.040
  Eth2 ~~                                                               
    Eth4             -0.005    0.001   -4.518    0.000   -0.005   -0.077
    Eth5             -0.001    0.000   -2.359    0.018   -0.001   -0.035
  Eth4 ~~                                                               
    Eth5             -0.001    0.000   -2.270    0.023   -0.001   -0.027

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .RL_1              0.690    0.149    4.624    0.000    0.690    0.333
   .RL_2              0.466    0.135    3.439    0.001    0.466    0.264
   .RL_3              0.640    0.129    4.965    0.000    0.640    0.366
   .RL_4              0.714    0.146    4.905    0.000    0.714    0.340
   .RL_5              0.552    0.134    4.112    0.000    0.552    0.310
   .RL_6              0.552    0.151    3.648    0.000    0.552    0.288
   .RL_7              0.527    0.133    3.970    0.000    0.527    0.285
   .RL_8              0.593    0.134    4.415    0.000    0.593    0.358
   .RL_9              0.462    0.140    3.310    0.001    0.462    0.248
   .RL_10             0.538    0.117    4.580    0.000    0.538    0.389
   .RL_11             0.681    0.126    5.413    0.000    0.681    0.360
   .RL_12             0.602    0.135    4.471    0.000    0.602    0.354
   .PI_1              0.565    0.079    7.134    0.000    0.565    0.472
   .PI_2              0.761    0.112    6.803    0.000    0.761    0.600
   .PI_3              0.676    0.116    5.816    0.000    0.676    0.492
   .PI_4              0.573    0.109    5.272    0.000    0.573    0.376
   .PI_5              0.746    0.101    7.367    0.000    0.746    0.470
   .PI_6              0.985    0.127    7.738    0.000    0.985    0.609
   .PI_7              0.706    0.101    6.998    0.000    0.706    0.494
   .Cplex_1           2.132    0.153   13.931    0.000    2.132    0.766
   .Cplex_2           2.457    0.154   16.004    0.000    2.457    0.834
   .Cplex_3           0.605    0.195    3.106    0.002    0.605    0.254
   .Cplex_4           0.360    0.154    2.332    0.020    0.360    0.205
   .Cont_1            0.726    0.131    5.553    0.000    0.726    0.400
   .Cont_2            0.716    0.129    5.535    0.000    0.716    0.404
   .Cont_3            0.876    0.140    6.253    0.000    0.876    0.472
   .Cont_4            0.313    0.138    2.265    0.024    0.313    0.182
   .RL                1.343    0.080   16.793    0.000    0.970    0.970
   .PI                0.285    0.090    3.166    0.002    0.452    0.452
    Cplex             0.652    0.062   10.503    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Control           1.090    0.063   17.203    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Age              80.342    5.238   15.338    0.000   80.342    1.000
    Gen2              0.231    0.006   39.102    0.000    0.231    1.000
    Eth1              0.103    0.011    9.424    0.000    0.103    1.000
    Eth2              0.084    0.011    8.027    0.000    0.084    1.000
    Eth4              0.052    0.009    5.789    0.000    0.052    1.000
    Eth5              0.012    0.005    2.497    0.013    0.012    1.000
```

---

***Fix 2:* Add in RL ~ Control path**

The variable “Control” theoretically makes sense to use as a control variable for RL, so that would be a good path to enter. When I try adding the covariate “Control” to the IV (“RL”), the model fit increases but it is still not superb (i.e., still below the cutoffs; see output below).

```
summary(SEMmodel2_2, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
lavaan 0.6-3 ended normally after 135 iterations

  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         85

  Number of observations                           506

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Model Fit Test Statistic                    3153.444
  Degrees of freedom                               476
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000

Model test baseline model:

  Minimum Function Test Statistic            24118.401
  Degrees of freedom                               513
  P-value                                        0.000

User model versus baseline model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.887
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.878

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.106
  90 Percent Confidence Interval          0.102  0.109
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                          0.000

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.116

Parameter Estimates:

  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured
  Standard Errors                             Standard

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  RL =~                                                                 
    RL_1              1.000                               1.167    0.810
    RL_2              0.973    0.031   31.535    0.000    1.135    0.855
    RL_3              0.897    0.030   30.246    0.000    1.047    0.793
    RL_4              1.001    0.032   31.216    0.000    1.168    0.806
    RL_5              0.956    0.031   31.208    0.000    1.116    0.836
    RL_6              1.003    0.032   31.135    0.000    1.170    0.846
    RL_7              0.994    0.031   31.575    0.000    1.160    0.853
    RL_8              0.891    0.029   30.376    0.000    1.040    0.808
    RL_9              1.013    0.032   31.526    0.000    1.182    0.865
    RL_10             0.793    0.026   29.943    0.000    0.926    0.788
    RL_11             0.940    0.031   30.822    0.000    1.098    0.798
    RL_12             0.896    0.030   30.240    0.000    1.045    0.802
  PI =~                                                                 
    PI_1              1.000                               0.796    0.728
    PI_2              0.890    0.035   25.129    0.000    0.709    0.629
    PI_3              1.047    0.040   26.039    0.000    0.834    0.711
    PI_4              1.226    0.044   27.801    0.000    0.977    0.792
    PI_5              1.153    0.043   26.925    0.000    0.918    0.729
    PI_6              0.996    0.041   24.261    0.000    0.794    0.624
    PI_7              1.069    0.040   26.552    0.000    0.851    0.712
  Cplex =~                                                              
    Cplex_1           1.000                               0.981    0.588
    Cplex_2           0.980    0.078   12.530    0.000    0.961    0.560
    Cplex_3           1.291    0.094   13.695    0.000    1.266    0.819
    Cplex_4           1.032    0.077   13.425    0.000    1.012    0.764
  Control =~                                                            
    Cont_1            1.000                               1.045    0.775
    Cont_2            0.981    0.037   26.468    0.000    1.025    0.770
    Cont_3            0.946    0.037   25.236    0.000    0.989    0.726
    Cont_4            1.136    0.041   27.398    0.000    1.188    0.906

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  PI ~                                                                  
    RL                0.196    0.020    9.692    0.000    0.288    0.288
    Age               0.011    0.003    4.476    0.000    0.014    0.127
    Cplex             0.435    0.034   12.887    0.000    0.536    0.536
    Control           0.297    0.030    9.870    0.000    0.390    0.390
    Gen2             -0.043    0.045   -0.960    0.337   -0.054   -0.026
    Eth1              0.488    0.086    5.660    0.000    0.613    0.197
    Eth2              0.040    0.072    0.560    0.575    0.051    0.015
    Eth4              0.126    0.095    1.328    0.184    0.158    0.036
    Eth5              0.494    0.258    1.918    0.055    0.621    0.067
  RL ~                                                                  
    Control           0.714    0.036   19.995    0.000    0.639    0.639

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  Age ~~                                                                
    Gen2              0.481    0.197    2.440    0.015    0.481    0.112
    Eth1             -0.490    0.098   -4.986    0.000   -0.490   -0.170
    Eth2             -0.065    0.120   -0.541    0.589   -0.065   -0.025
    Eth4             -0.219    0.076   -2.889    0.004   -0.219   -0.107
    Eth5              0.005    0.045    0.112    0.911    0.005    0.005
  Gen2 ~~                                                               
    Eth1              0.011    0.007    1.562    0.118    0.011    0.073
    Eth2             -0.004    0.006   -0.653    0.514   -0.004   -0.028
    Eth4             -0.010    0.004   -2.344    0.019   -0.010   -0.092
    Eth5             -0.002    0.002   -1.143    0.253   -0.002   -0.044
  Eth1 ~~                                                               
    Eth2             -0.011    0.002   -5.749    0.000   -0.011   -0.116
    Eth4             -0.006    0.001   -4.731    0.000   -0.006   -0.088
    Eth5             -0.001    0.001   -2.388    0.017   -0.001   -0.040
  Eth2 ~~                                                               
    Eth4             -0.005    0.001   -4.518    0.000   -0.005   -0.077
    Eth5             -0.001    0.000   -2.359    0.018   -0.001   -0.035
  Eth4 ~~                                                               
    Eth5             -0.001    0.000   -2.270    0.023   -0.001   -0.027

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .RL_1              0.712    0.150    4.753    0.000    0.712    0.343
   .RL_2              0.474    0.136    3.482    0.000    0.474    0.269
   .RL_3              0.649    0.130    5.011    0.000    0.649    0.372
   .RL_4              0.735    0.146    5.023    0.000    0.735    0.350
   .RL_5              0.537    0.135    3.968    0.000    0.537    0.301
   .RL_6              0.546    0.152    3.582    0.000    0.546    0.285
   .RL_7              0.505    0.134    3.767    0.000    0.505    0.273
   .RL_8              0.576    0.135    4.265    0.000    0.576    0.348
   .RL_9              0.469    0.140    3.340    0.001    0.469    0.251
   .RL_10             0.525    0.118    4.446    0.000    0.525    0.380
   .RL_11             0.685    0.127    5.409    0.000    0.685    0.363
   .RL_12             0.607    0.135    4.480    0.000    0.607    0.357
   .PI_1              0.562    0.079    7.086    0.000    0.562    0.470
   .PI_2              0.766    0.112    6.853    0.000    0.766    0.604
   .PI_3              0.679    0.116    5.849    0.000    0.679    0.494
   .PI_4              0.568    0.109    5.226    0.000    0.568    0.373
   .PI_5              0.744    0.101    7.339    0.000    0.744    0.469
   .PI_6              0.988    0.127    7.764    0.000    0.988    0.611
   .PI_7              0.705    0.101    6.987    0.000    0.705    0.493
   .Cplex_1           1.821    0.175   10.416    0.000    1.821    0.654
   .Cplex_2           2.022    0.178   11.387    0.000    2.022    0.686
   .Cplex_3           0.785    0.211    3.727    0.000    0.785    0.329
   .Cplex_4           0.733    0.156    4.707    0.000    0.733    0.417
   .Cont_1            0.725    0.131    5.536    0.000    0.725    0.399
   .Cont_2            0.720    0.129    5.571    0.000    0.720    0.407
   .Cont_3            0.878    0.140    6.274    0.000    0.878    0.473
   .Cont_4            0.309    0.138    2.232    0.026    0.309    0.180
   .RL                0.805    0.046   17.395    0.000    0.591    0.591
   .PI                0.182    0.025    7.243    0.000    0.287    0.287
    Cplex             0.962    0.105    9.168    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Control           1.092    0.063   17.211    0.000    1.000    1.000
    Age              80.342    5.238   15.338    0.000   80.342    1.000
    Gen2              0.231    0.006   39.102    0.000    0.231    1.000
    Eth1              0.103    0.011    9.424    0.000    0.103    1.000
    Eth2              0.084    0.011    8.027    0.000    0.084    1.000
    Eth4              0.052    0.009    5.789    0.000    0.052    1.000
    Eth5              0.012    0.005    2.497    0.013    0.012    1.000
```

Since the model was good but not great, I looked back to the modification indices one more time (see output below).

```
subset(MOD2_2, mi >1000)
        lhs op     rhs       mi   epc sepc.lv sepc.all sepc.nox
 Control  ~      PI 2582.365 1.722   1.312    1.312    1.312
   Cplex  ~      PI 2521.305 1.196   0.971    0.971    0.971
 Control  ~   Cplex 2511.789 0.773   0.725    0.725    0.725
   Cplex  ~ Control 2511.789 0.681   0.725    0.725    0.725
   Cplex ~~ Control 2511.789 0.744   0.725    0.725    0.725
   Cplex  ~      RL 2312.928 0.461   0.548    0.548    0.548
      RL  ~      PI 1729.922 1.308   0.893    0.893    0.893
      RL  ~   Cplex 1668.640 0.585   0.492    0.492    0.492
      RL ~~   Cplex 1668.640 0.563   0.639    0.639    0.639
 Control =~ Cplex_4 1121.039 0.863   0.902    0.680    0.680
      RL =~ Cplex_4 1092.501 0.612   0.715    0.539    0.539
      PI =~ Cplex_4 1062.157 1.407   1.120    0.845    0.845
```

The modification indices suggest either more non-recursive paths or things that theoretically don't make sense. Indicating I should either go with the first fix of adding the non-recursive (RL ~ PI) path or just stick with fix 2 as my final model with just good but not great model fit. *Would that be a correct conclusion?*

Any help to my queries in italics or suggestions about how to move forward given this information would be wildly welcomed.

If there’s any other information you need me to add, please let me know and I will add it asap. Additionally, if I somehow missed another post that already answers this question (I scoured the site and couldn’t find anything but I could’ve missed something in my search), feel free to just direct me to that post instead.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely "whack-a-mole" as my advisor likes to put it. Your model is very clearly misspecified because your exogenous latent variables are uncorrelated with each other and with the exogenous predictors. This is an extremely strong assumption to make, is almost surely not what you intended to have happen, and will cause the misspecification to propagate to other parts of the model and show up in these absurd modification indices.

Try respecifying the model by adding covariances among all the exogenous variables, latent and observed. Check to ensure all the covariances you intend are there by using `lavaanify(SEMmodel2, OPTIONS)`, where `OPTIONS` stands in for the options you included in the call to `lavaan()`. Refit the model once you have ensured your specifications are correct, and then check the modification indices again. This time, they should only refer to indicator disturbances (because the only restrictions you're making are on the covariances between the disturbances and the other observed variables (i.e., you're assuming them to be zero in the measurement models).

Comment: Dang, that was so helpful. Thank you - that did the trick. Glad it was simple and just a mistaken assumption on my part. I thought I had remembered something about how it's inappropriate to correlate exogenous latent variables but that must have been an incorrectly remembered piece of information on my part. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to upvote and mark my answer as selected if you feel the problem is solved :)